# XNA or C# Pop-up progress bar for the LoadContent() method

Tags: c#, popup, xna, progress-bar

We wrote a small game using Microsoft's XNA Game Studio 3.1.
The LoadContent() takes a long time because, other than loading models, and config files, we're also running some one-time (per run) terrain analysis.

We are ***not*** C# or XNA programmers... we're Java programmers, and want to be able to give the user some feedback that the system is loading.

Preferably, this will be through a simple pop-up with a progress bar that will say something simple like "loading please wait".  The progress bar doesn't have to be a 0 to 1 progress bar, it can instead be one of those 'back and forth' progress bars.

I was hoping for some quick copy-paste ready code to just do that - as it is not a central piece of our project, nor do we have a need to delve into too much documentation.

I appreciate you time, effort, and possible donation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find or make an animated gif of your "back and forth" progress bar, you should be able to use something like the *[XNA Gif Animation Library](http://xnagif.codeplex.com/)* (http://xnagif.codeplex.com/).